# Change Lightning Record Page Template button Is not working

Tags: lightning, user-record, page-template

I want to change **Template** for My Account Lightning Record Page.

However when I click on the **Change** button nothings happens.

[image]

Did anyone have the same problem before ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Works fine for me. What browser are you using? Have you tried different ones to see if it happens on all?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I use Google Chrome. Yes, it works fine for other objects.